# Vba find the cell which equivalent to array

Tags: arrays, vba

I wish to calculate the price of the memory item which I already include in the MemList with 95% discount and other item remain the original price. Here is my code but it seems doesn't work:

[image: Example]

```
Sub String_Array_Memory()
Dim MemList() As Variant
Dim Price As Integer
Dim Element As Variant
Dim memmatch As Boolean
Price = 0

MemList = Array("Sandisk CZ50 16 GB", _
"Sandisk CZ50 32 GB", _
"Sandisk CZ50 64 GB", _
"Sandisk CZ50 128 GB", _
"Adata SU650 120 GB", _
"Adata SU650 240 GB", _
"Adata SU650 480 GB", _
"Adata SU650 960 GB", _
"Crucial MX500 2 TB", _
"Kingston A2000 250 GB", _
"Kingston A2000 1 TB", _
"Kingston NV1 2 TB")

For Each Mem In MemList
Mem = Range("G5:G" & lastrow & "")
If Element = MemList() Then
    memmatch = True
    Price = Price + Mem.Offset(0, 3) * 0.95

Else
    memmatch = False
    Price = Price + Mem.Offset(0, 3)
End If
Next
MsgBox (Price)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work. I get $15,504 as the result, is that what you expect?

Things to consider:

1. You have to leave the cell below last element (Galax in this case empty) for .End(xlDown) to work properly.
2. "test3" is the codename of the sheet I have used for testing, change accordingly.
3. Exchanged the variables Mem and Element to have better meaning.

```
    Sub String_Array_Memory()

        Dim MemList() As Variant
        Dim Price As Currency
        Dim Element As Variant
        Dim memmatch As Boolean
        Dim Mem As Variant
        
        Price = 0
        
        MemList = Array("Sandisk CZ50 16 GB", _
        "Sandisk CZ50 32 GB", _
        "Sandisk CZ50 64 GB", _
        "Sandisk CZ50 128 GB", _
        "Adata SU650 120 GB", _
        "Adata SU650 240 GB", _
        "Adata SU650 480 GB", _
        "Adata SU650 960 GB", _
        "Crucial MX500 2 TB", _
        "Kingston A2000 250 GB", _
        "Kingston A2000 1 TB", _
        "Kingston NV1 2 TB")
        
        Dim i As Long
        
        For i = 5 To test3.Range("G5").End(xlDown).Row
            
            Element = test3.Range("G" & i)
            
            For Each Mem In MemList
                memmatch = False
                If Element = Mem Then
                    Price = Price + test3.Range("G" & i).Offset(0, 3) * 0.95
                    memmatch = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next Mem
            
            If memmatch = False Then
                Price = Price + test3.Range("G" & i).Offset(0, 3)
            End If
            
        Next i
        
        MsgBox (Price)
        
    End Sub
```

Comment: Problem here is Application.EnableEvents don't affect userform events. So, the boolean approach is a workaround.